# Getting error while foreman start in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, express, foreman

getting following message if I try to start foreman. I am not sure what should I do further to solve. I guess its express related error but still any help to solve this error will be really really appreciated!

```
2013-04-21T10:39:54.622588+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy fc0f862 by suchak.maulik179@gmail.com
2013-04-21T10:39:54.695655+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-04-21T10:39:54.972645+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-04-21T10:39:55.470897+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server/server.js`
2013-04-21T10:39:56.617617+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-21T10:39:56.618147+00:00 app[web.1]:     server = module.exports = express();
2013-04-21T10:39:56.617811+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/server/server.js:7
2013-04-21T10:39:56.618147+00:00 app[web.1]:                               ^
2013-04-21T10:39:56.621350+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: object is not a function
2013-04-21T10:39:56.621350+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
2013-04-21T10:39:56.621350+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
2013-04-21T10:39:56.621350+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2013-04-21T10:39:56.621350+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
2013-04-21T10:39:56.621350+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
2013-04-21T10:39:56.621350+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2013-04-21T10:39:56.621350+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/server.js:7:31)
2013-04-21T10:39:57.852895+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-21T10:39:57.867532+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-04-21T10:40:37.078893+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by suchak.maulik179@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get that error when your code expects Express version 3.x but your Express module is version 2.x

Answer (score 0):

I think your project depends on [express](https://npmjs.org/package/express).

Make sure you have `express` installed and load the `express` module before the `express()` line.

```
var express = require('express'),
    server = module.exports = express();
```

Comment: It is installed and even I can see that in node_modules folder. Is there any other way to check that?

Answer (score 0):

Could you check whether the express dependency is added in package.json file of your code?

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "3.1.x"
},
```

Heroku installs dependent packages into the server using this file. 3.x refers to the version of the express. If it is already there then please check you have added right version for your project.